# Prove Jumps of a Poisson Process are Poisson RVs

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I'm working through Varadhan Stochastic Processes, and I can't follow along with his proof. He defines a Poisson process on page 13 with the following criteria:

1. With probability $1$, $N(0)=0$, $N(t)$ is integer valued, right continuous with left limits and non-decreasing in $t$
2. For each $h>0$, the distribution of $N(t+h)-N(t)$ is independent of $t$
3. The random variables $N(t'_j) - N(t_j)$ are mutually independent if the intervals $[t_j,t_j']$ are non-overlapping.
4. $P(N(t+h) - N(t) \ge 2) = P(N(h) \ge 2) = o(h)$

We want to prove that $N(t+s) - N(t)$ or just $N(t)$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda t$. He seems to break up this interval into $n$ non-overlapping subintervals, and take advantage of property 3 to use moment generating functions. However I am unclear why he is saying:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[E \left[\exp\left(-\sigma N\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right] \right]^{nt} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\exp\left[(nt)\log\left( E \left[\exp\left(-\sigma N\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right]\right) \right] = \exp(-tg(\sigma))
$$
where $g(\sigma) = \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left[1 - E\left[\exp\left(-\sigma N(\frac{1}{n})\right) \right] \right]$

Varadhan: (https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/spring06/spring06.1.pdf)
(we're looking at page 2)

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? How he derives this equality or why it is useful to prove the claim?

Comment: The first one. Why it's true.

Comment: That's simply the definition of the exponential function. Note that $$a^x = \exp(x \log a),$$ (here $x=nt$ and $a = \mathbb{E}\exp(-\sigma N(1/n))$).

Comment: no the second equality. I added the first equality myself.

Comment: Maybe because $\log(x)\approx x-1$  when $x\to 1$, roughly speaking?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be a differentiable (non-negative) function such that $f(0)=1$. Then

$$\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} n \log (f(1/n)) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log (f(1/n))-\log (f(0))}{\frac{1}{n}} \\ &= \frac{d}{dx} \log(f(x)) \bigg|_{x=0} \\ &= \frac{1}{f(0)} f'(0) = f'(0). \end{align*}$$

Applying this identity for

$$f(x) := \mathbb{E} \exp \left(- \sigma N (x) \right)$$

gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log \left( \mathbb{E} \exp \left[- \sigma N(1/n) \right] \right) = f'(0) = -g(\sigma). \tag{1}$$

Here we have used that

$$f'(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}} = - g(\sigma)$$

by definition of $g$. From $(1)$ the second equality in your question follows easily from the continuity of $\exp$.